# Temperature as the integral of kinetic energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature

Heat is the macroscopic phenomenon related to the kinetic energy of the particles. So, I wonder if there is a way to express the absolute temperature as the volume integral of the kinetic energy of the particles over a control volume.

I remember having found something like in Wikipedia, but without a proper reference, and I can't find it again anyway.

Comment: In theory, you could just define temperature as $T=\oint_V v^2(\mathbf{x})\ dm$

Comment: That simple ? How do you manage the consistency of units between K and m²/s².kg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. Temperature is related to the average energy per degree of freedom in a system. For a volume of ideal gas containing N molecules, each having three degrees of freedom, the energy integrated over the volume is $E = \frac{3}{2}Nk_BT$. $k_B$ is Boltmann's constant.

Comment: By any chance, do you have the analytic form of the original integral that leads to this result ?

Comment: All you need to know is the total number of degrees of freedom in the volume. In the ideal gas case this is 3 per molecule, so the integral is simply $\frac{3}{2}kT\int{dV\rho}$ where $\rho$ is the molecular number density.

Answer (score 1):

Given some particle distribution $f(t,\,\mathbf x,\,\mathbf v)$, one can define the pressure as,
$$
p=\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{Tr}\left[\int m\mathbf w\mathbf wf\left(t,\,\mathbf x,\,\mathbf v\right)\,\mathrm d^3x\right]
$$
where $\mathbf w=\mathbf v-\mathbf V$ is the *relative velocity* where $\mathbf v$ is the particle velocity and $\mathbf V$ the bulk flow. We also define the particle density,
$$
n=\int f\left(t,\,\mathbf x,\,\mathbf v\right)\,\mathrm d^3x
$$
Then, in thermodynamic equilibrium, the distribution function is essentially [Maxwellian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) with some $T$, thus we can write $p=nT$ or,
$$
T=p/n=\frac{1}{3n}\operatorname{Tr}\left[\int m\mathbf w\mathbf wf\left(t,\,\mathbf x,\,\mathbf v\right)\,\mathrm d^3x\right]
$$
which may or may not be convenient to use.

Comment: I assume you write vectors in bold, but what are Tr and t here ?

Comment: Tr is trace, t is time.

Comment: @AurélienPierre yes, vectors are bold, as is standard convention, $t$ is time and Tr is the trace. Probably could just do a scalar product of $\lVert\mathbf w\rVert$, but it's sometimes nice to be complete.

Comment: Standard just in America ;-)

Comment: @AurélienPierre last I checked [ISO 80000-2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2) standards are global, not American.

Comment: In Europe and sometimes in Canada, we put arrows on vectors. Anyway, I have never seen vectors in bold outside of US textbooks.

Comment: @AurélienPierre it might be that over-arrows are also permissible, but I believe it was that ISO 31-XI said bold fonts ought to be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're misremembering is an integral *over* temperature, such as $U=\int C_V dT$ expressing total thermal energy in terms of heat capacity.

Comment: No, I remember this one. I'm really looking for an equivalence motion-temperature at molecular level over a control volume. Which seems reasonable since it's 2 different kinds of energy.